# Phone Attachments not working with a scheduled email

Tags: email

We have multiple Windows Phones deployed with several of our staff. We also have a system that sends out an automated email with a PDF attachment. The phones all have a PDF reader program installed.

The emails sent with PDF attachments do not work on the Windows Phone. When the email is received, it shows no content (not even the body of the message that is sent with the attachment) simply a link to 'Download message content'. Clicking on this makes something load for a very short amount of time, but nothing shows up afterwards. Things that I have tried:

- Problem with the scheduling system - No other users are reporting issues with any other scheduled reports. When I try sending the self same reports to my personal email (not on a Windows Phone) the attachment views just fine
- Problem with type of file - Figuring that the issue may be with PDF files, I tried using the option to send the report as an Excel file. This again did not work.
- Problem with the email itself - I have tried logging into email account that is on the Windows Phone in desktop Outlook, and when viewing the email I can correctly see the content and open the attachment
- Problem with receiving PDFs altogether - I (and several other users) are able to send a PDF file to that email address and the emails work perfectly fine on the Windows Phone.

I am almost certain this is a hardware error, unless someone can tell me otherwise. I have tried removing and re-adding the account to the Windows Phone.

Comment: What phone models do you have and what's the OS version and mail app version on those phones? Are both up-to-date? Do emails without any attachments work? How big are the attachments? Have you tried any other email apps? Have you tried manually composing the same email with the same attachment (or forwarding an automatically generated one)?

Comment: What is a typical message size, and have you set the option to "always download full message and internet images" (wording from Windows 10 Mobile)?